# Some sort of frequency outbreak is turning people into static silhouettes

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember a girl in some post apocalyptic camp. She finds a mobile phone, which are forbidden because there is some kind of outbreak that is turning people into some sort of static silhouette. She starts to talk to some guy over the phone and I remember that she leaves this camp and goes over some kind of wasteland to meet with him in the city.

During her trip, she stops by this house, where an old crazy black dude lives and I think that he tries to kill her and it got something to do with his late wife. Anyway, when she comes to the city, she finds out that the guy, she was talking to over the phone, was also turned into static.

Well, I hope that someone remembers this movie. It was definitely after 2000 (somewhere between 2005 and 2010, I think) and USA.

Comment: Hi and welcome to M&TV. Do you remember the approximate year and country of origin?

Comment: after 2000 definitely. USA

Comment: somewhere between 2005 and 2010 I think.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like [Pulse 3](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1323946/combined) from 2008.

> Seven years into the invasion, humankind has fled the cities where billions have died from a plague spread through the internet. JUSTINE (17) dreams of a life beyond her squalid refugee camp where all technology is taboo. She discovers the last working laptop and opens it like Pandora's Box. Someone is waiting for her online. And that someone wants desperately to meet her. The only catch, she must return to the city. With a longing that surpasses fear, Justine embarks on a terrifying journey back to the heart of where it all began. What waits there is something she could not possibly have imagined.

People are turning into static ghosts, she meets an old black man who's going insane along the way, and it ends like you described. The 2nd sequel to [Pulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_(2006_film)), which was based on a [Japanese horror film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_(2001_film)). Here's a clip from the first scene:

Comment: @duckyR6 No problem, but don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it.